# Angular 5 how to get data from Nested Json file

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, http-status-code-404

Trying to fetch data from nested json.

```
Error: 1. <h3>{{sampledata}}</h3> displaying [object Object]
       2. <p>{{sampleDataModel.Title}}</p> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

sampledata.json:

```
{
    "isSuccessfull": true,
    "Model": [
    {
        "SampleDataModel": [ 
            {
            "Title": "SampleData 1",
            "Description": "Some Text"
            }
        ],

        "SampleDetailModel": [
               {
                "Name": "Donald Trump",
                "Id": "111",
                "Country": "USA"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

sampledata.services.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class SampledataService {

  private _url = 'assets/data/sampledata.json'

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getData(){

    return this._http.get(this._url)
      .map((resSampleData: Response) => resSampleData.json());

  }

}
```

sampledata.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SampledataService } from '../sampledata.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sampledata',
  templateUrl: './sampledata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sampledata.component.css']
})
export class SampledataComponent implements OnInit {

  sampledata = [];
  sampleDataModel = [];
  sampleDetailModel = [];

  constructor(private _sampledataservice: SampledataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this._sampledataservice.getData()
      .subscribe(resData => { 
        this.sampledata = resData;
        this.sampleDataModel = resData.Model.SampleDataModel;
        this.sampleDetailModel = resData.Model.SampleDetailModel });
  }

}
```

sampledata.component.html:

```
<h3>{{sampledata}}</h3>
<p>{{sampleDataModel.Title}}</p>
```

app.module.ts:

```
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SampledataComponent
  ],
 imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, HttpModule
 ],
 providers: [HttpClientModule, SampledataService],
```

angular-cli.json:

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "assets/data/sampledata.json",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

**My Questions is:**

1. How do I get these values to display on sampledata.component.html,

sampledata and sampleDataModel.Title?

If anyone of you have any idea on how to solve this issue, please help to suggest the solutions to me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the issue is here `private _url = 'assets/sampledatajson'`

You may need to put a dot `.` before `json` like this

```
private _url = 'assets/sampledata.json'
```

Comment: Yes. private _url = 'assets/data/sampledata.json'. Changed it. I don't get any error now. How the data is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

In your `sampledata.component.html` you are binding wrong variable... Bind `sampledata` instead of `sampledataModel`. Because in subscribe you are assigning values to `this.sampledata`.

Comment: I'm using "sampledata", and on I see [object Object]. Also, I need to get "SampleDataModel.Title" which is in the json object. How do I get "SampleDataModel.Title"?

Answer (score -1):

You need to look closely at your JSON and see exactly where your properties are... You can access the data you want with:

```ts
this.sampledata = resData;
this.sampleDataModel = resData.Model[0].SampleDataModel[0];
this.sampleDetailModel = resData.Model[0].SampleDetailModel[0];
```

Then to display `sampleData` without iteration or anything else, use the `json` pipe:

```html
<pre>{{sampledata | json}}</pre>
<p>{{sampleDataModel?.Title}}</p>
```

Also, all your variables are objects, instead of arrays, that you have declared them, so do...

```ts
sampledata = {};
sampleDataModel = {};
sampleDetailModel = {};
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsko3c?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**